# How to set filename for base64 rendered pdf using object tag?

Tags: html, pdf, base64

Well I am using the following code to render a PDF that is returned from a webservice as base64 string.

```html
<html>
  <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,{!pdfStampingResponse.pdfBase64}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" class="internal">
    <param name="view" value="fitH" />            
  </object>
</html>
```

This works well but I want to set the download filename when user tries to save the file. Somehow I am unable to find a working solution. Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: I know this is very old but, just in case Avidev9 sees it, did you ever find a solution to this? Or can anyone else help? I am currently facing the same problem.  The solution by Stu below doesn't work for me. Thanks.

Comment: You need to set the Content Disposition header as shown in this answer to set the file download name. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1741508/728610

Comment: Does anyone know how to set the title on the header when i embed a pdf?

Answer (score 4):

please try this

```
const FILE_NAME = 'myfile.pdf';
const file_header = ';headers=filename';

fetch('https:your-url/myfile.pdf?dl=0').then(r => r.blob())
.then(blob=>{
  const f = new FileReader();
  f.onload = () => myPdfViewer.src = f.result.replace(';', file_header + encodeURIComponent(FILE_NAME) + ';');
  f.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
```

Then insert id myPdfViewer to an iframe.
I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code syntax

```
<object data="data/test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
  alt : <a href="data/test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
</object>
```

Found this [here](http://joliclic.free.fr/html/object-tag/en/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `download="yourfilename"` in anchor tag.

The download attribute specifies that the target will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink.

PS:This attribute is only used if the href attribute is set.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way around this so that I can control the name?
>
> > No. You cannot control the name of a file stored at user local filesystem.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061387/9913319