# How to change fpdf filename output(' ', S)?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fpdf

I created PDF file using FPDF in laravel. I used string output destination to preview pdf file from blade using iframe.

controller.php

```
$output = $pdf->Output('','S');
$output = base64_encode($output);
return $output;
exit;
```

blade.php

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{{ $output }}" type='application/pdf' width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
```

How I can change the default filename when try to download it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the default save as name for a an <embed> or <iframe> that uses a Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061354/set-the-default-save-as-name-for-a-an-embed-or-iframe-that-uses-a-blob)

Comment: @Veve I've tried and still haven't changed anything