# How download a file from Amazon S3 with express.js and request.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I am try download a file from Amazon S3 with express.js and request.js using the pipe method.

But when I go to: **localhost:3000/download**
the browser download a file with the name of "download" How I can Set the file name for the browser to download such as "myFile.zip"?

This is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  request('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/object.zip')
  .pipe(res.set('Content-Type', 'application/zip'))
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Any help is going to be appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP has a header called `Content-Disposition` that allows you to specify a filename. Here's your program setting it to download to myFile.zip:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  request('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/object.zip')
  .pipe(res.set('Content-Type', 'application/zip').set('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="myFile.zip"')
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1741508/2329281

Comment: Thanks so much, this is the solution!

Comment: What is require("request")? Library can't be found. Also, are the parens correctly matching?